# WCF - Multiple Processes

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

I have an wcf  SERVICE that get a request of branch code and return 5 products list values.

In server side, each product process takes about 6 sec to be completed, so if I run synchronous it will take 30 seconds. I altered my server code and run them in parallel. It works fine, but it seems that each parallel process get threads from IIS threadspool.

Now I am thinking to run asynchronous each  product processes and when all will be finished then return the whole list of products to client. It will be grateful if you help me about that..

How can I run asynchronous  these processes in server side ? No matter if client run sync or async. That what I need is to run async product processes in order to serve the results faster.

Comment: Basically, your server should be designed to handle a singlr request, then change your server to be able to serve multi threaded requests. Just make sure your code is thread protected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this asynchronous approach with generics type:

```
namespace InterNameSpace
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestClass
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Task<AnyComplexType> xpto(string baseUrl, string getAsyncUrl);
    }
}

namespace Test
{

    ServiceBehaviorAttribute(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class TestClass : ITestClass
    {

        public async Task<AnyComplexType> xpto(string baseUrl, string getAsyncUrl)
        {
            try
            {    
                return await TestAux.Auxiliar.RetrieveDeserializeObject<AnyComplexType>(baseUrl, getAsyncUrl);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create a Product complex-type, pass it to your call method. In this method use the keyword async and task to call the deserialized method as asynchronous. 
Your deserialized method recieve the baseurl and the controller route. As a genetic type you can pass different complex-type and deserialaze this object and return it.

```
namespace TestAux
{
    public class Auxiliar
    {

        public static async Task<T> RetrieveDeserializeObject<T>(string baseUrl, string getAsyncUrl) where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                T deserializeObject = null;
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(getAsyncUrl);

                //throw an exception if not successful
                if (response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    // DeserializeObject our concrete class into a JSON String
                    deserializeObject = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content));
                }
                return deserializeObject;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ilansch why random place.Are you sure? We do not know the any name of class neither his method. What matter is the concept, not if the name match....

Comment: In general, what is the suggested method for this issue ? Surely, someone had to build such an application with multiples processes. First thing that I came to my mind is "parallel processing". Is it really so bad ?

Comment: @StDeveloper with asynchronous programming approach its possible building service with multiple thread and task. This implementation is known as the Promise Model of Concurrency, that offer you a "promise" that work will be completed at a later point.